# how to copy multiple files from one directory to another with progressBar in c# window form

Tags: c#, winforms, multi-select, openfiledialog, file-copying

I'm going to copy multiple files from one directory to another but the problem i face is that "my code copy only one file from one directory to another" .

actually i'm going to make the clone of File explorer with specified directory . I've tried to copy multiple files from one directory to another but my code work on only coping one file from multiple files.

```
OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
ofd.Multiselect = true;
if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK){ 
 string dess = path_textBox.Text;
 File.Copy(ofd.FileName, dess + "\\" + ofd.SafeFileName, true);}
```

I expect the output is "Coping multiple files from one directory to another in c# window form"

Comment: Take a look at `OpenFileDialog.SafeFileNames`

Comment: File.Copy(ofd.FileName, dess + "\\" + ofd.SafeFileNames, true); @skyoxZ like that????

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to use a FolderBrowserDialog to select the destination path and copy a list files there? Then, you have to decide if a progress is shown for each file copied or the partial/total bytes.

Comment: @Jimi i want to copy selected multiple files "not folders" so that's why i use Open FileDialog instead of FolderBrowserDialog

Comment: Well, just to be sure what the procedure should include. So, you already have a destination directory, you just need a `for each` loop, using the array of file names returned by OpenFileDialog as the destination name, `Path.Combine`d with the destination directory. That's all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy Multiple Files

```
string strDestinationFolder = @"D:\Barcode Copied";
OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
ofd.Multiselect = true;
if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) 
{
   foreach (string fileName in ofd.FileNames)
   {
      System.IO.File.Copy(fileName, strDestinationFolder + @"\" + System.IO.Path.GetFileName(fileName));
    }
 }
```

Comment: You could use the SaveFileNames collection. This collection includes just the file name, without the path, so you don't need `Path.GetFileName`. You already have it. To build a path, it's usually better to use `Path.Combine()`

Answer (score 0):

1. Get all files and put it to list
2. Put it to for loop
3. Update progress using loop index